Durrett Probability Exercise 2.1.5, why it's necessary to discuss discontinuities of the measure?
I'm working on exercise 2.1.5 of Durrett's PTE.
Below is the solution I prepared:

However, in a solution manual I found the following solution


I got the following questions:
first, if the solution manual is correct, why my approach is wrong (which step does not go through)?
second, for the solution manual, I don't see why it's necessary to introduce the set of discontinuities for $\mu$ denoted by $D_\mu$.

In your solution to (i), the third equality doesn't quite work without justification. The issue is that you could be summing over an uncountable set of $y$-s, so it's unclear what this sum means. That's why the switch to integration is necessary in the solution manual. Continuity ensures that (as you noted) $\mu$ assigns zero measure to singletons outside a countable collection. This allows the summation $\sum_y$ to be well-defined: in reality, even though the set of all $y$-s can be uncountable, the sum only needs to be taken only over the countable set of mutual discontinuities of $\mu$ and $\nu$. The sum over the remaining $y$-s is $0$ thanks to continuity, which is why the abuse of notation (summing over an uncountable set) is allowable.

Thank you very much! This is very helpful!
